# Typescript: do not allow implicit any => class, but do allow any => interface

Tags: typescript

How can I configure my tsconfig.json to not allow values of type `any` to be converted to classes but do allow them to be converted to interfaces? Is it possible?

```
interface Foo {}
class Bar {
    someMemberMethod() { }
}

const value: any = JSON.parse(someJsonString);

const valueFoo: Foo = value; // should be fine

const valueBar: Bar = value; // should throw syntax error
valueBar.someMemberMethod();
```

Using interfaces to tell the type system the layout of a json response is nice, but i'd like the system to prevent me from implying that a plain object can be implicitly casted to a class.

Comment: what do you want achieve by that? simple code example would be also helpful.

Comment: I added a bit more detail

Comment: You can easily avoid problem it by seting interface directly to first variable without `any`: `const value: Foo = JSON.parse(someJsonString);`.

Answer (score 1):

> values of type any to be converted

There is no compiler option that will prevent an *explicit* `any` to be incompatible with some other type.

Anything that is `any` is by definition assignable from and to anything.

The `noImplicitAny` is a flag regarding **inference** and simply prevents mistakes where you might think something isn't any but it is inferred to be any. It doesn't change how `any` behaves.